# Estimating how many of the first $10,000$ Fibonacci numbers start with the digit $9$

Tags: probability, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers, estimation, decimal-expansion

Consider the problem of estimating how many of the first $10,000$ Fibonacci numbers begin with the digit $9$.

The only ideas I have so far:

- Obviously, if we assume that the every first digit is equally likely, the answer is around $1000$ (Note: `Dietrich Burde` points out that is wrong. $0$ can't be the first digit, so I should divide by $9$, not $10$).
- Listing out the Fibonacci numbers: $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, ...$, we can see that their first digits, $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 1, ...$ seem to follow a pattern somewhat similar to $1, 2, 3, 5, 8$, with $9$'s introduced less often. So perhaps the answer is less than $1000$.

I'll put the answer here:

> **456** of the first $10,000$ Fibonacci numbers start with the digit $9$.

Any ideas/hints of how to estimate or compute this analytically?

Comment: But the number cannot start with digit $0$, so dividing by $10$ is not right for the first point. See also [quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-digit-appears-the-most-in-the-Fibonacci-sequence-and-the-Lucas-sequence) for your question, using Benford's law.

Comment: Look at Benford's law : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law ; Numbers starting wigh 9 should be 4.6%, and you find 4.56%, totally conform to the law.

Comment: See also [A008963](https://oeis.org/A008963) at OEIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fibonacci numbers are roughly $\varphi^n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. Asking whether these numbers start with a 9 is the same as asking whether their logs mod 1 fall between log 9 and log 10. But those logs are $n \log(\varphi) - .5 \log(5)$. Since $\log(\varphi)$ is irrational, we expect multiples of it (mod 1) to be evenly distributed around the mod 1 circle.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), at least from a statistical point of view, you should get around
$$10000\left(\log10-\log9\right)=457.5749\dots$$
which is quite close to your calculated value. That being said, it's not an exact calculation.